# Keep getting the output as zero

Tags: c, output

I'm relatively new to C, and wanted to create a program to calculate the months of service.

I keep getting the output as 0, no idea why.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
int ddjoin, mmjoin, yyjoin, ddlev, mmlev, yylev;
int mmdiff = 0;
int mmserv = 0;
int y2y1 = 0;



//Getting Joining Date
printf("When did you join us ? (dd/mm/yyyy)\n");

printf("Date (dd)\n");
scanf_s("%d", &ddjoin);

printf("Month (mm)\n");
scanf_s("%d", &mmjoin);

printf("year (yyyy)\"\n");
scanf_s("%d", &yyjoin);

printf("You joined us on %d/%d/%d\n", ddjoin, mmjoin, yyjoin);

//Getting Termination Date
printf("When did you retire ? (dd/mm/yyyy)\n");

printf("Date (dd)\n");
scanf_s("%d", &ddlev);

printf("Month (mm)\n");
scanf_s("%d", &mmlev);

printf("year (yyyy)\"\n");
scanf_s("%d", &yylev);

printf("You retired on %d/%d/%d\n", ddlev, mmlev, yylev);

y2y1 == (yylev - yyjoin - 1) * 12;
mmdiff == 12 - mmjoin;
mmserv == y2y1 + mmdiff + mmlev;

printf("Your months in service are %d\n", mmserv);

return 0;


}
```

The output is zero. I tried not assigning them a value of 0 at the start, but then it gives me the "unlocalized variable error".

Comment: Why do you use scanf_s? Just use scanf("%d", &variable).

Comment: Why are you using `==`?

Answer (score 3):

```
y2y1 == (yylev - yyjoin - 1) * 12;    // == operator is to compare values
mmdiff == 12 - mmjoin;
mmserv == y2y1 + mmdiff + mmlev;
```

Don't use `==` (its a relational operator) to assign values . Use assignment operator `=` .
Write them as -

```
y2y1 = (yylev - yyjoin - 1) * 12;
mmdiff = 12 - mmjoin;
mmserv = y2y1 + mmdiff + mmlev;
```